# Segment class in ConcurrentHashMap usage

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

Looking into implementation of ConcurrentHashMap, I see that when trying to manipulate it(put/remove), value is found and this value is then used as lock for synchronized code which performs actual manipulation. This way only that bucket is locked where value actually exists.

I also see a class Segment declared and in many resources available online its mentioned that this is used to implement concurrency. But I couldn't find any code in implementation using Segment for synchronization implementation.

So what actually I miss here?

I am looking into java 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [sources of OpenJDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#l1370), the class `Segment` bears a comment:

> ```
>     /**
>      * Stripped-down version of helper class used in previous version,
>      * declared for the sake of serialization compatibility
>      */
>     static class Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock implements Serializable {
>         ...
>     }
> ```

So it seems to be present only for backwards-compatibility.